# reading from a binary filestream into a vb.net structure

Tags: vb.net, filestream

I'm wanting to read blocks of bytes into some sort of structure from a filestream in vb.net

I tried defining a structure, which would have included a few byte arrays in its definition, but VB.NET does not allow me to pre-define array sizes in the structure.

Essentially, I want to read a block of bytes into a pre-defined structure, and then calling items from that structure, instead of reading a field at a time from the filestream.

The byte arrays are just byte(2) and byte(4).  The byte(2) are LSB and MSB values for a number, and the byte(4) is the same, but for a larger value.  Can I used Int16 and Int32 for these, respectively?

For 4 bytes that are to be a 4 character ASCII string, how would I define that without using an array.

Here is what I have now:

```
Private Structure file_hdr
        Public hdr_len As Byte
        Public protocol_ver As Byte
        Public profile_ver As Int16
        Public data_size As Int32
        Public data_type1 As Char
        Public data_type2 As Char
        Public data_type3 As Char
        Public data_type4 As Char
        Public crc As Int16
    End Structure
```

And I'm trying to emulate this record structure from the incoming file:
[image: FITS FILE HEADER]

How do I get there?

Dwight

Comment: You may use Int16 and Int32 if you convert between them to/from a byte array. See the [**`BitConverter` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: The structure has at most six fields (pay attention to the Size column in the specification).  Trying to be clever by overlaying the stream bytes to the structure will be more work than using a `BinaryReader` to read each field.  Set the `BinaryReader`'s encoding to ASCII and read the 4 bytes (chars) of the  ".FIT" field as a `Char()` and then create a new `String` from that array.